# Проблема с элементом управления Slider в XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

XAML Slider при изменение атрибута Minimum и получение его значения в элемент TextBox выдает ошибку:

> System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.".

Значение атрибута Minimum обычно равно 0. И когда нужно получить значение в текст бокс достаточно:

```
TxtBlock.Text = Convert.ToString(slider1.Value);
```

Но когда меняется значение Minimum на другое например 100 то получается ошибка:

> System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.".
> Вот как выглядит XAML:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Ticks="100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000" TickFrequency="100" Foreground="#FF1844DA" ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Value="100" Minimum="100" Maximum="1000"/>
```

Думал нужно изменить значение атрибута Value на начальное базовое значение и все получится, но это никак не помогло.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Используйте Binding для Value к свойству типа int и не будет у вас никогда null. Вообще в WPF без привязки данных мало чего вменяемого можно написать. И проблемы лезут изо всех щелей, типа вашей.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, что ответили. Можете дать пример того как нужно использовать Binding для этой задачи. Мы к сожалению еще не дошли до этой темы в колледже. А изучать полностью документацию ради 1-ой проблемы не хочется. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Спасибо большое @aepot! Я немного посмотрел про Binding и сделал привязку TextBox его атрибута Text к значению атрибута Value эл-та Slider, и благодаря этой теме я могу избавиться от лишних обработчиков.

Comment: Ура, я рад что получилось